# Tell TortoiseGit to pull all of origin

Tags: git, tortoisegit

I have a git repository established by TortoiseGit which pulls updates from all remote branches regardless of which branch it is locally.

```
git.exe pull -v --progress       "origin"
```

But when i copy that repository directory to another directory, and have TortoiseGit create a brand new branch, its pull command narrows its scope to just that branch.

```
git.exe pull -v --progress       "origin" test
```

I cannot find anything in TortoiseGit that controls this behaviour. What should be done to revert this configuration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I opened a Git bash console to run a general pull, and it mention the main branch for this directory is *not* being tracked. I do not know the difference in behaviour between TortoiseGit and raw Git.

> $ git pull
>
> remote: Counting objects: 32, done.
>
> remote: Compressing objects: 100% (23/23), done.
>
> remote: Total 23 (delta 19), reused 0 (delta 0)
>
> Unpacking objects: 100% (23/23), done.
>
> From bitbucket.org:repository
>
> 50bf7c6..a08a735  master     -> origin/master
>
> There is no tracking information for the current branch.
>
> Please specify which branch you want to merge with. See git-pull(1) for details
>
> ```
> git pull <remote> <branch>
> ```
>
> If you wish to set tracking information for this branch you can do so with:
>
> ```
> git branch --set-upstream test origin/<branch>
> ```

So I ran the suggestion

> user@MACHINE /D/Projects/test_branch (test)
>
> $ git branch
> --set-upstream test origin/test
>
> Branch test set up to track remote branch test from origin.

And after that TortoiseGit appears to now be able to pull with a broader scope.

> git.exe pull -v --progress       "origin"

While it has achieved what i was desiring, i do not have the fundamental understanding to properly tell why TortoiseGit behaves the way it does.

Comment: TortoiseGit has several ways it can confuse someone new to Git as they learn the command line and this is one of them. It infers branch "master," the default branch name, for you, while command line git won't do that for you. In other words, if you push to your remote, it will push to origin/master for you; but command line git will complain that this branch isn't being tracked, and that you'll need to explicitly set a default, or explicitly say where you want to push. You're basically coping with that difference in functionality. It's too bad TortoiseGit doesn't just set this for you.

Comment: Thanks to both icelava and @Chris Moschini.  In the process of getting set up with a repository I moved to GitHub, I set up a new origin but lost tracking on my master branch.  Since I did not realize I had lost tracking, TortoiseGit was explicitly specifying the master branch and not pulling any new branches or tags.  When I did a pull from the command line, I got the following message: 

If you wish to set tracking information for this branch you can do so with:

    git branch --set-upstream-to=<remote>/<branch> master

After this, a git pull retrieved the remote branches and tags.

Answer (score 0):

Are those branch being tracked?

```
git branch -vv
```

For example, if you want to track local branch `test` with remote branch `test`:

```
git branch -u origin/test test
```

Then you can perform a `git pull`.

Comment: It is tracking the test branch. the problem is i want it to pull _more_ than just the test branch i.e. also the development branch which it originally branched out from. The "git pull" command issued by TortoiseGit only narrows the pull to "origin test" which is not desired; i prefer it to be the original scope, which was more broadly "origin".